# Create Pandas table from dictionary of lists with each item as an index

Tags: python, pandas

Example input:

```
sample_dict = {"Pam":["cat", "dog", "bird"], 
               "Bron":["cat", "bird", "dragon"]
               }
```

Desired output:

```
       Pam | Bron 
Cat    O     O
Dog    O     X
Bird   O     O
Dragon X     O
```

Can this be done without having to create two versions of the dictionary and a pivot table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [MultiLabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) and transpose:

```
sample_dict = {"Pam":["cat", "dog", "bird"], 
               "Bron":["cat", "bird", "dragon"]
               }

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(list(sample_dict.values())),
                  columns=mlb.classes_,
                  index=list(sample_dict.keys())).T
print (df)
        Pam  Bron
bird      1     1
cat       1     1
dog       1     0
dragon    0     1
```

Or only pandas solution with [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), `split` and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), last use [`DataFrame.max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html):

```
df = pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(sample_dict))
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.stack().fillna(0).astype(int).max(level=1)
print (df)
        Bron  Pam
bird       1    1
cat        1    1
dog        0    1
dragon     1    0
```

And last use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df = df.replace({1:'O', 0:'X'})
print (df)
       Pam Bron
bird     O    O
cat      O    O
dog      O    X
dragon   X    O
```

Comment: A minor improvement of the `pandas`-only version is to use `downcast=int` of `fillna` rather than calling `astype(int)`. The latter creates one more copy of the data frame.